# Can I find adjacent rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a log table that records user events. These are ordered by a timestamp.

| id | event | user | context | timecreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | login | 234 | 0 | 65535 |
| 8 | open | 234 | 5 | 65536 |
| 13 | open | 234 | 9 | 65539 |
| 17 | open | 234 | 8 | 65512 |
| 43 | login | 128 | 0 | 65513 |
| 44 | login | 293 | 0 | 65515 |
| 65 | open | 293 | 5 | 65516 |
| 66 | open | 234 | 5 | 65519 |
| 97 | login | 567 | 0 | 65521 |
| 99 | open | 567 | 9 | 65528 |

I want a query that finds the first `event='open'` rows that are adjacent-next to `event='login'` rows for the same user id (and other possible filters

psuedo-example:

`select * from log where event='open' and context=5 and timecreated > (select timecreated from log where event='login' and user = (the same as the previous query) limit 1)`.

In the table above this would match the rows

| id | event | user | context | timecreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | open | 234 | 5 | 65536 |
| 65 | open | 293 | 5 | 65516 |
| 99 | open | 567 | 9 | 65528 |

Is this possible in a MySQL statement?

Comment: please explain more about the other possible filters; are those on *both* the open row you want and the login row?  or even just one or the other?

Comment: @ysth I would want to `group by` user and then `order by` timecreated for that grouping, where the "first" matching row was `event='login'` and the "second" matching row in the group was `event='open'`, but don't know how to query between rows in a group.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using the [LAG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, LAG(event) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY timecreated) AS prev_event
    FROM log
) t
WHERE event = 'open'
AND prev_event = 'login'
AND context = 5
```

If you are using MySQL < 8, you could use:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM log o
JOIN log l
    ON l.event = 'login'
    AND o.user = l.user
    AND o.timecreated > l.timecreated
WHERE o.event = 'open'
AND o.context = 5
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM log
    WHERE user = o.user
    AND timecreated > l.timecreated
    AND timecreated < o.timecreated
);
```

Comment: No, it isn't preferable to use id; ids should be treated as opaque values, and not expected to be in temporal order.  Though using event and/or id to break ties is a good idea

Comment: there are many possible cases; a couple examples: open and login records are written by different services, with their own event streams and timing, and don't always arrive in order (but do have the correct timestamp), or a code error results in some records not being written, and they are reproduced later manually from error logs.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from test t
where t.event = 'open' and
    t.user =
   (select user
    from test
    where id = (select max(id) from test where  id < t.id) and event = 'login');
```